# New Azure PHP API - generateSharedAccessUrl

Tags: php, azure

In the interoperability version of Azure PHP API there was a service call  "generateSharedAccessUrl" to generate "password" for  access to a blob inside a private container.

In the new version that microsoft have released does not appear to have the same call.

Using the new (Oct 2012) version , how do i set the shared access url key?

below is the cut down version of the old call:

```
  $storageClient->generateSharedAccessUrl();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SAS token support is not currently in the GitHub Azure PHP SDK and based on some discussion It seems that there are some plans to add it eventually, however I do not have any further information on when or it will be available. A [work item](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-php/issues/628) to the same SDK is also requested.

If it is necessary for your project the option you have is to write your own code to make it happen or leverage the previous version available on CodePlex. As SDK is open source, you can submit your code back to SDK to make it useful for others.