# Shared Access Signatures in new PHP SDK

Tags: php, azure

Apparently support for it is not in the new SDK

[New Azure PHP API - generateSharedAccessUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392112/new-azure-php-api-generatesharedaccessurl)

as seen here

What is the alternative way of setting them?

Thank you

Comment: Please see answer below. If you feel it answers the question, you should mark it as such. I cannot keep responding to any more questions posted as comments, as this question will be closed and migrated to chat, which would not help the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any SAS wrapper functions in the php sdk.

Here's the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415.aspx) with all details around Shared Access Signature and how to create one. With this, you should be able to create your own simple php wrapper to create an SAS.

Alternatively: If you want, you can create your own internal service (running on the same vm?), implemented in Java or .net that generates a SAS for you. For Java, you'll find the proper class [here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/microsoft-azure-api/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/services/blob/client), and MSDN docs for generating SAS in Java [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh875756.aspx).

Comment: http://phpazure.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Shared%20Access%20Signature you can see an example of the method being used there - it seems as though they got rid of it. Is it worth using an older version of the SDK?

Comment: No - you don't want to use that sdk. It's unsupported and has no knowledge of the latest storage protocol updates. If anything, grab the SAS code from that sdk and implement your own method.

Comment: but isnt the SAS code from that sdk out of date? It seems like that SDK is 4.0.1 - I assume this is a previous version?

Comment: *and implement your own method* - You're going to need to write it yourself, but I was suggesting using the SAS method in the older sdk as a starting point.

Comment: When are microsoft going to provide support for this, I find it odd that they updated their drivers and didn't support this

Comment: No telling when this would appear. Feel free to add it, push it to your own git repo, then issue a pull request for the Windows Azure team to consider. The sdk is completely open-source and you are welcome to contribute to it!

Comment: Ive given the old SDK drivers a shot, seems to work perfectly. Baring in mind, I dont need all of the Azure functionalities, just this part.