# PHP Create Working Azure Signature For Blob Storage

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage, signature

Can someone please provide me a working example (php) for creating the signature which is needed when building a "[Shared Access Signatures URL](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/#beispiele-fr-shared-access-signatures)" for microsoft azure blob service which is still working in 2015?
All examples and tutorials which I've found on the internet are using the old unofficial azure sdk or the created signature from the provided code isn't working because I always got the following error:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of  Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:2c406e11-0001-00b1-3a5a-0eb263000000 Time:2015-10-24T12:46:34.5256055Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Here are the codes which i tried: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766452/shared-access-signatures-function-for-php-authenticationfailed) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureossds/archive/2015/05/12/generating-shared-access-signature-sas-using-php.aspx)

So that's my code at the moment:

```
$key = "myKeyBase64==";
$sig = getSASForBlob("accName","containerName", "abc.mp3", "b", "r", date("c", time() + 30000), $key);
$url = getBlobUrl("accName","containerName","abc.mp3","b","r",date("c", time() + 30000),$sig);

echo($url);

function getSASForBlob($accountName,$container, $blob, $resourceType, $permissions, $expiry,$key){
     /* Create the signature */
     $_arraysign = array();
     $_arraysign[] = $permissions;
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = $expiry;
     $_arraysign[] = '/' . $accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob;
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = "2014-02-14"; //the API version is now required
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = '';

     $_str2sign = implode("\n", $_arraysign);

     return base64_encode(
     hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(utf8_encode($_str2sign)), base64_decode($key), true)
     );
}

 function getBlobUrl($accountName,$container,$blob,$resourceType,$permissions,$expiry,$_signature){
     /* Create the signed query part */
     $_parts = array();
     $_parts[] = (!empty($expiry))?'se=' . urlencode($expiry):'';
     $_parts[] = 'sr=' . $resourceType;
     $_parts[] = (!empty($permissions))?'sp=' . $permissions:'';
     $_parts[] = 'sig=' . urlencode($_signature);
     $_parts[] = 'sv=2014-02-14';

     /* Create the signed blob URL */
     $_url = 'https://'
     .$accountName.'.blob.core.windows.net/'
     . $container . '/'
     . $blob . '?'
     . implode('&', $_parts);

     return $_url;
 }
```

Comment: Can you share your code for creating Shared Access Signature please?

Comment: I tried this one (the last post) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766452/shared-access-signatures-function-for-php-authenticationfailed) and this one [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureossds/archive/2015/05/12/generating-shared-access-signature-sas-using-php.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links. One more question: Did you change the service version mentioned in the code samples you're using or you used the same service version?

Comment: I changed the api version as mentioned and I also tried the newest one.

Comment: If you're using version "2015-02-21" or newer, there's a breaking change in the way canonicalized resource string is created. You would need to prepend "blob" in your canonicalized resource. So if you're using "account-name/container-name" in your code, you have to use "blob/account-name/container-name". However if you're using version before this, then "account-name/container-name" should work. Let me also try it out on my end and post an answer once I have some working code.

Comment: I'm currently using version 2014-02-14. I added the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one issue with your code:

Essentially you're formatting the expiry time in an incorrect format. Your expiry time should be formatted in `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ` format.

Please try the following code:

```
$expiry = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", time() + 30000);
$sig = getSASForBlob("accName","containerName", "abc.mp3", "b", "r", $expiry, $key);
$url = getBlobUrl("accName","containerName","abc.mp3","b","r",$expiry,$sig);
```

There's no need for you to change `getSASForBlob` and `getBlobUrl` function.

I tried with the code above and was able to download blob using SAS URL.

Comment: for me its saying. `<AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2021-07-16T19:26:15Z /actblobcontainers/actcontainer 2014-02-14 </AuthenticationErrorDetail>`